# How to create a custom dictionary in python?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

There is what i have in source:

```
"VirtualizationType": "hvm",
"Tags": [
         {
          "Value": "Test",
          "Key": "Name"
         }
        ]
```

and here is a bit of my code:

```
for item in result:
   temp = {"Tags": item["Value"], "VirtualizationType": item["VirtualizationType"]}
      output.append(temp)
```

I can easily export **VirtualizationType** but couldn`t do it with **Tags**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of how to create a dictionary in Python, from [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
tel = {'jack': 4098, 'sape': 4139}
```

In this example `jack`, `snape` are the keys and `4098`, `4139` are the values.

Values can also be strings and a list of dictionary like in your case, 
your code can modified into this:

```
dictionary = {"Virtualization Type" : "hvm", "Tags" : [{"Value" : "Test", "Key" : "Name"}] } #Runs in the python interpreter with no errors
```

Comment: I have a problems with loop running. It fails anyway I trying to .get() the "Tags".

Comment: @user3729941 You should explain your question more.

Comment: Ive found an answer:
    `def find_value(tags):
    value = ""
       if not tags: return value

    for tag in tags:
        val = tag.get("Key", None)
        if val == "Value":
            value = tag["Value"]
    return value`

Comment: @user3729941 Great to hear, you solved it! Since your new here, next time try to choose a better title for your question.